# How to add spacing between elements of bootstrap enabled html table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10952/ displays 8 table elements, but I'm unable to add spacing between each element.

I've tried :

```
cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3"
```

as well as:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

but these options do not seem to have desired effect.

```html
<div class="center">

  <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-3">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-3" col-md-offset-2>
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-3">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>




        <td class="col-md-4">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-3">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-3" col-md-offset-2>
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-3">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>




        <td class="col-md-4">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ module.hrefTitle }}" target="_blank">test2</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="{{module.title}}" href='test");'>test</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve? Is it cell spacing?

Comment: @WesFoster Yes, cell spacing

Comment: You'll want to use `border-spacing` on the table

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding the following:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try adding this :

```
table {
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:10px 10px;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add a `<br/>` in all the table th or td(first column).

```
 <tr>
    <td><br/>Firstname<span class="red">*</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/></td>
      <td id="fnameError" class="red">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><br/>Lastname<span class="red">*</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"/></td>
      <td id="nameError" class="red">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

This work fine for me. :D

Comment: I'm commenting because this is your first posting on SO. Thanks for participating! If you look at the comments to the question you can probably guess why your answer might not be up-voted. Although it might be correct, there seems to be a way of doing this that involves considerably less change to the original code. Whenever you answer, consider the reputation of the person asking the question as a guide to the level of the answer he or she will expect. Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for an updated answer, you can add class from bootstrap that helps you add padding/margin to the cells (e.g. p-3, p-4, etc.)

More information can be found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<table class="table mt-3 table-sm table_col_padding"> </table>
```

**SCSS**

```
.table_col_padding{
  thead{
    tr{
      th{
        padding-right: 1rem;
      }
    }
  }
  tbody{
    tr{
      td{
        padding-right: 1rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```